# Is there a standard name for the following code pattern?

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

I find I use the following pattern when I have a known execution path between several conditionals. I will define my test cases in a Map (in this example a POJO) and use the conditionals to make a key lookup. I've typically used the term `predicate`.

Is there a standard name to this pattern and if so what is the history or context around its use?

```
var predicates = {
  negateRegexp: function (value, operator) {
    return !operator.regex.test(value);
  },
  negateOperand: function (value, operator) {
    return value !== operator.operand;
  },
  affirmRegexp: function (value, operator) {
    return operator.regex.test(value);
  },
  affirmOperand: function (value, operator) {
    return value === operator.operand;
  }
};

var predicateKey = (operator.prefix === '!' ? 'negate' : 'affirm') +
  (operator.regexp ? 'Regexp' : 'Operand');

var testResult = predicates[predicateKey](value, operator);

if (testResult) {
  doSomethingWith(value);
}
```

*I used JavaScript for the example as that is what I usually work in. But I'm sure I've seen this pattern in other languages (even OOP-typed ones like Java)*

Comment: [Wikipedia/Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OOP, this is known as the [*strategy* pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Given the lookup table, it also resembles the [*interpreter* pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern) however for a really simple language in your case. Using strategies for causing side effects might also be known as the [*command* pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), but I'd argue that's not the case in your example.

In FP, this pattern doesn't have a specific name, it's just how you do things - although the lookup method might be called a higher-order function as it returns another function.

Btw, the term [*predicate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)) usually means just a function that returns a boolean, while this fits in your case it doesn't have anything to do with the abstraction pattern.